# Xamarin Comparison between string list and label Text

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a novice in Xamarin, I have a list of two strings and I want to compare if the elements of the list in lower case are equal to elements of a label in lower case.

When I add `.ToLower()` to a element of a label, the debug stop and I do not know why.

Here is my code :

```
Dictionary<int, string> WordsList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
Dictionary<int, string> WordsList2 = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public TestWords()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   mywordsdatabase = new MyWordsDatabase();

   var mywords = mywordsdatabase.GetWords();

   int i = 0;

   // TestAnswer.IsVisible = false;
   foreach (var myword in mywords)
   {
       WordsList[i] = myword.Word1;
       WordsList2[i] = myword.Word2.ToLower(); // this is ok

       i++;
   }

   word10.Text = WordsList[0];
   word11.Text = WordsList[1];

   word20.Focus(); 
   word21.Focus();
}

//Correction for the test
void OnOKTest(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     int yes = 0;
     int no = 0;

     //############ if == #############
     if (WordsList2[0] == word20.Text.ToLower())  // but this is not accepted
     {
         true0.Text = "✔";
         yes++;
     }

     if (WordsList2[1] == word21.Text.ToLower())  // but this is not accepted
     {
         true1.Text = "✔";
         yes++;
     }
}
```

Here is my xaml:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="word10" Text="Your Text" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Label x:Name="word11" Text="Your Text" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Entry x:Name="word20" Placeholder="The word traduction" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ></Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="word21" Placeholder="The word traduction" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ></Entry>
    <Label x:Name="true0" Text="" FontSize="20"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
    <Label x:Name="true1" Text="" FontSize="20"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" />
</Grid>
```

Thanks

Comment: what does "not accepted" mean?  Does it give a compilation error?  A runtime exception?

Comment: Check if myword.Word2 is a string or not..

Comment: @Atul   myword.Word2 is a string

Comment: @Jason not accepted mean the debbug stop and  a runtime exception

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems that you are using `ToLower()` on a null object.

Change your `Ifs` to something like this:

```
if (string.Equals (WordsList2.ElementAtOrDefault (0), word20.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{ 
}

if (string.Equals (WordsList2.ElementAtOrDefault (1), word21.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{ 
}
```

Using `string.Equals` is a better way to compare strings as you can defined different way to validate.

With `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` this you don't have to explicitly convert it to lower case.

With `ElementAtOrDefault` you prevent having and IndexOutOfBounds exception since if there's not item for the index specified it will return the default value which in your case for `strings` de default value is `NULL`. To use this you need to add `using System.Linq`.

Comment: Thanks this is working with some modification in Xamarin;   if (string.Equals(WordsList2[0], word20.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)){}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "not accepted" but the default value for the `Text` property of the `Entry` component is `null`. Make sure that it has a value before calling `ToLower()` on it.

Comment: I use "word20.Focus(); " to get the value entered